# Need your advise on switching my monitor for both Desktop/laptop but only one active

Tags: laptop

I use hp pavillion p6370in and monitor hp2009 series 20 inch lcd which has VGA and DVI-D at the back of Monitor. Currently I have plugged the VGA Port-Desktop to VGA-Monitor and use it. I have got my laptop one week before that has mini vga port and 2 HDMI Port, 2 USB Ports for which I connect my mouse and keyboard to that USB Ports. I need to use my desktop monitor which I use for desktop to be connected to laptop when I use laptop and  switch to desktop when I use desktop. Can I Utilize the DVI-D also to connect the laptop ? I dont know to purchase which cable and also I can't afford to get an additional monitor

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. At resolutions 1920x1200@60 Hz or smaller, you only-need a Single-Link DVI-D connection, which can easily be converted to HDMI or vice versa with a cheap adapter, or with a cable that has a HDMI connector at one end and DVI-D at the other.

For resolutions larger than 1920x1200 or for higher refresh rates, it would be trickier as a Dual-Link DVI-D connection would be needed then, and conversion between that and HDMI would be more difficult and would require a much more expensive active adapter.

If your monitor is described by [this manual,](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01725831) then its optimum resolution is 1600x900 @ 60 Hz, so it is easily handled by a Single-Link DVI-D connection, and so cheap DVI-D <-> HDMI adapters *can* be used with it.

According to the manual, the monitor should automatically sense which connection is being used, but if necessary, there should be a "Source" button on the monitor that can be used to switch between the input connectors (for example, if you have both the desktop and the laptop powered on at the same time).

Something like [this cable](https://www.amazon.de/AmazonBasics-Adapterkabel-HDMI-auf-DVI-Schwarz/dp/B014I8UQJY/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=hdmi+dvi&qid=1557202183&s=gateway&sr=8-5) or a regular DVI-D cable together with [this adapter](https://www.amazon.de/deleyCON-HDMI-DVI-Adapter-Kabel-vergoldete/dp/B01K1QFRXW/ref=sr_1_8?keywords=hdmi+dvi&qid=1557202290&s=gateway&sr=8-8) should work just fine.

Although it would also work electrically, I would recommend **not** getting [this type of adapter](https://www.amazon.de/Rankie-Adapter-Vergoldet-Konverter-Schwarz/dp/B00Z09EID6/ref=sxbs_sxwds-stvp?keywords=hdmi+dvi&pd_rd_i=B00Z09EID6&pd_rd_r=7006f7fc-b8d6-425c-b01b-9c847db5997b&pd_rd_w=jlysJ&pd_rd_wg=SRa6e&pf_rd_p=6d84c7ba-ae72-4e53-b9a4-5df18ccb370e&pf_rd_r=M3T4VYRPK4EGCPET5TBW&qid=1557202322&s=gateway) for this use case, as the combination of an adapter + a DVI-D connector all protruding out of of laptop-side HDMI connector could be awkward and might easily damage the laptop with any kind of twisting motion. Anything with just a HDMI connector and at least a bit of cable at the laptop end would be mechanically safer for the laptop.